# Who choreographs meetings between China and the United States?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, china

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avebny5UeB8

Who choreographs meetings between China and the United States? CNBC claimed in the video above that the whole meeting was choreographed, but by whom and how? Is there some kind of process, and do both sides know exactly what the other side is going to say in advance? How is the whole thing choreographed?

Comment: I want to know who in the White House has been responsible for choreographing President Biden's press conferences and other interactions with the America Press.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the U.S. it is the [Major Events Division](https://www.state.gov/bureaus-offices/secretary-of-state/office-of-the-chief-of-protocol/major-events-division/) and [Visits Division](https://www.state.gov/bureaus-offices/secretary-of-state/office-of-the-chief-of-protocol/visits-division/) of the Department of State who work with the visiting leader’s delegation and embassy staff to create a detailed schedule from beginning to end. The two sides work together and have to **agree** on the choreography of the event. There is also a Ceremonials Division. The Major Events Division works on major events and negotiations, and the Visits Division specializes in foreign liaisons.

For the CCP it's less obvious. Governments have *event organizers* who include a variety of staff, manage locations, proceedings, decorations, security liaison, host city arrangements, transport, airport logistics, hotels, credentials management, production contract management, press releases, host foreign government communications and agreements, intra-agency meeting arrangements.

Comment: I would emphasize that both sides have a whole bunch of staff to organize these kind of things and the two sides work together and have to **agree** on the choreography of the event.

Comment: Do you know by chance not names but the number of people working in these events divisions? Is it 0-10, 10-100, 100-1000, 1000-10000, ... for the US or China?

Comment: That figure is probably secret and exempt from transparency law for safety, it's cia/fbi folk. I would guess that it's 50-75 admin for every department, I have absolutely no idea, and about 250 -500 staff for the entourage for a major state visit.